# When are modified closed questions reviewed again, and how is this visible?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen, review

I got [my question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/756793/) closed (by a bot? It looks like it from the first comment) and when I saw this, I rephrased and tried to abide to the comments (should be more focused).
This happened yesterday, and the question is still closed, but I cannot understand whether it's been reviewed and rejected a second time, it is in the review pipeline, is not going to be considered or what.

It is the first time I get a question rejected, so I don't know what to look for and expect. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

You should be seeing something like this at the top of your question:
[image]

I can't remember if the list of close voters is visible only to users with the close vote privilege or whether you as a question owner can see the list of users, too, but in any case: Bots don't close questions on physics.SE, users do!

"This post was edited and submitted for review yesterday" should be visible to all users looking at this post and it means that the review is still ongoing. When the review finishes, the question will either get reopened or the text will change to say *"... and failed to reopen the post"* after the time stamp saying when it was submitted for review.

Comment: I can't see who closed it, no list of users or anything - the only thing I could see is the first comment, as I wrote, which looks like it's been written by a bot and restates the "reason" for the question being closed. Hence the question. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: If you, the question owner, cannot see the blue box with guidance about reopening the question, that's a bug. In the past, users who have experienced this bug have discovered they were running some browser extension which hides the box.